# TypeError: urls.toObject is not a function Mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

Hi everyone I'm trying to do a basic to object function in my code I required mongoose and its send me this error I don't understand why: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: urls.toObject is not a function. It's in the get function, hope for help.

```js
const express = require("express");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const Url = require("../models/Url");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const HttpError = require("../models/http-errors");

const getTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  let urls;
  try {
    urls = await Url.find({});
    res.json({ urls });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      "Something went wrong, could not find a Url.",
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }
  res.json({ urls: urls.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};

const addTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { content } = req.body;
  const createdPlace = new Url({
    content: content,
    enable: false,
  });
  // Sending it To Mongo
  try {
    await createdPlace.save();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Creating Place fails mongo");
    return next(error);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
};


exports.getTodo = getTodo;
exports.addTodo = addTodo;
```

Comment: move the `res.json({ urls: urls.toObject({ getters: true }) });` to the `try` block

Comment: That's not the Point I believe I tried it and I get another error:Error: Something went wrong, could not find a Url.
    at getTodo (C:\Users\ethan\Desktop\all projects\ToDo\ToDo-Back-master\controllers\url-controllers.js:31:19)

Comment: But if console.log(URLs) I get the object.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is a list of object so I needed to map it in order to do a toObject function.

```js
  res.json({
    url: url.map((url) => url.toObject({ getters: true })),
  });
```